# Dynamic, semantic URL routes

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I'm creating semantic url routes in Codeigniter where I'm pulling data from 5 different tables to be used in combinations as parameters, such as;

```
helloworld.com/universe
helloworld.com/universe/earth
helloworld.com/universe/earth/australia
helloworld.com/universe/earth/australia/melbourne
helloworld.com/universe/earth/australia/melbourne/city
```

Where I am pulling rows from the universe, world, country, city, and region tables. So there a route written for every `helloworld.com/(universe)` and `helloworld.com/universe1/(planet)`, and so on.

As our database currently is, it's generating 85000 pages as routes in our `routes.php` file. I expect this to grow into the millions over the next few months.

It's performing fine as it as at the moment, but is this method sustainable? Will it affect performance on page loads if its routing using a file with millions of routes in it?

Comment: Depends how much memory you have available to your database and if your tables are properly indexed.  Indexing is very important when you have thousands, or millions, of rows.

Comment: It's not the database that will see millions of rows. That should stay relatively small for now. It's the combination of rows that will be written as routes in our codeigniter routes file that I'm concerned about.

Comment: Ah, I don't know much about codeigniter or how the router works so I'll leave that for someone else.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that there are only these levels of routes, you can substantially reduce the number of lines in your routes.php. Here's how:

add these in your routes.php

```
$route['universe/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)'] = 'controller/function/$1/$2/$3/$4';
$route['universe/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)'] = 'controller/function/$1/$2/$3';
$route['universe/(.*)/(.*)/'] = 'controller/function/$1/$2';
$route['universe/(.*)'] = 'controller/function/$1';
```

The (.*) that you see is a RegEx that means "Anything".

For the url helloworld.com/universe/earth/australia/melbourne/city , the route will consider `$route['universe/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)']` and will route you to `controller/function/$1/$2/$3/$4` where $1, $2, $3 and $4 would be the parameters of the function in your controller.

Here, in your function you can check for the parameters and do your computation accordingly.

Make sure that the route is in that order itself, as CodeIgniter assumes the top most one is highest priority.

Comment: The problem is that the `universe` segement in the url can also be anything, and we are already using `$route['(.*)']` for something else. I forgot to mention that, sorry.

Comment: I don't think that would matter. Just add `$route[(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/]` at the top of the route. And a similar logic should help.

Comment: `$route[(.*)]` would then be used for functions in two different controllers. That won't work.